# Create a Custom SoapFault error message in the response for camel cxf webservice

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I am working on a camel based cxf-webservice. I have to show all types of error messages in my responses which I am doing properly in my service layer. But if a request is invalidated still I was getting a correct response.

For the following type of request

```
<soapenv:Body>
    ...
    <!--Optional:-->
    <prod:CandidateMaximumQuantity/>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <prod:CandidatePerPageMaximumQuantity>100</prod:CandidatePerPageMaximumQuantity>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <prod:CandidateDisplayStartSequenceNumber>1</prod:CandidateDisplayStartSequenceNumber>
    ...
</soapenv:Body>
```

In the soap validator i am getting invalid decimal value. expected at least one digit.
After writing the following code in my cxf-context I am able to do the input request validation.

But in the response I

```
<cxf:properties>
<entry key="allowStreaming" value="false" />
<entry key="schema-validation-enabled"     value="${isSchemaValidationEnabled}" />
</cxf:properties>
```

Where isSchemaValidationEnabled = true.

So I am getting the following response in my SOAP UI.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is    not a valid value for 'integer'.</faultstring>
   </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
```

My requirement is to create custom error message, so that I can propagate the SOAP error in to my response.And I can show a format of following message

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

   <soapenv:Body>
      <prod:Response ServiceVersionNumber=" " xmlns:prod="****">
         <prod:TransactionDetail>
        <prod:ApplicationTransactionID>***Request</prod:ApplicationTransactionID>
        <prod:ServiceTransactionID/>
        <prod:TransactionTimestamp>2015-05-05T05:33:52</prod:TransactionTimestamp>
     </prod:TransactionDetail>
     <prod:TransactionResult>
        <prod:SeverityText>Error</prod:SeverityText>
        <prod:ResultID>CM018</prod:ResultID>
        <prod:ResultText>No candidates resulted for the given input criteria.</prod:ResultText>
        <prod:ResultMessage>
           <prod:ResultDescription>List of service interface is not available for the given Service name or Service Version  number</prod:ResultDescription>
        </prod:ResultMessage>
     </prod:TransactionResult>
  </prod:Response>
```

Please someone respond to the query.